# Extract unique terms from a document

Tags: elasticsearch, feature-extraction, tf-idf

I am looking for an efficient way to extract terms from a document that are unique to him and don't appear in any other document.
The naive way is to index all documents in a database such as elasticsearch and search each term in the new documents in all the index. This will probably be very inefficient.
The problem is a kind of feature extraction problem.
My questions is whether elasticsearch or any other tool can provide an efficient method to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

Well if you have a big amount of data I'll suggest you use the Redis database to store and fetch the data in Redis you can also pre-cache your data so that it would be easy to load again
Redis also uses Key-value pair but is very fast than python dictionary

and for making it unique you can make some key-value combination

for more details about Redis check this
`https://realpython.com/python-redis/`

Answer (score 1):

```
**try this**

import re
 
# Declare a dictionary
dict = {}
 
# Method to check whether the word
# exists in dictionary or not
def uniqueWord(Word):
 
    if Word in dict:
 
        # If the word exists in dictionary then
        # simply increase its count
        dict[words] += 1
 
    else:
 
        # If the word does not exists in
        # dictionary update the dictionary
        # and make its count 1
        dict.update({words: 1})
 
# Driver code
if __name__ == '__main__':
     
    string = "Java is great. Grails is also great"
     
    # re.split() method is used to split
    # all the words in a string separated
    # by non-alphanumeric characters (\W)
    ListOfWords = re.split("[\W]+", string)
 
    # Extract each word from ListOfWords
    # and pass it to the method uniqueWord()
    for words in ListOfWords:
        uniqueWord(words)
 
    # Iterate over dictionary if the value
    # of the key is 1, then print the element
    for elements in dict:
        if dict[elements] == 1:
            print(elements)
```

Comment: Thanks! I am talking about a big amount of documents and each new document should be calculated very quickly. I guess I can manage my own dictionary on some key value store but I would prefer using something that already exists.